# How to confirm my files are snappy compresses in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, compression, snappy

So I compressed my table in hive using snappy compression and it did get compress. The size was reduced.

But when i run hadoop fs -lsr /hive/user.db/table_name, I see no file extensions with .snappy.

I want to know if they really were snappy compressed or not?

Comment: Show us how did you perform snappy compression

Comment: set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;

Comment: What was the file format? `parquet, avro, ORC, text....`

Comment: I have tried with both ORC and SequenceFiles.
In orc i also set "orc.compress"="SNAPPY" in table properties